# Get rendered image size in pdf file

Tags: c#, vb.net, itext

I am new in itextsharp, how come when i get the image (say original image size is 1000 X 40, and scaled image size is 20 X 20) in existing PDF, when i retrieved it, it gets the original size.

How do you get the re sized image size (the 20 X 20)?

Comment: In your case the image is imported into the PDF in its original dimensions. Only for display on the page it is transformed to cover a 20x20 area (whichever units you may use here). If you want to extract images in the dimensions as visible on the PDF page, you also have to extract the current transformations in the content stream where the image is displayed.

Comment: BTW, that current transformation might include rotation and skewing, not merely stretching. If you want to get an image just like the image you see in the file, some distortion with some image lib might be necessary.